# How to merge data into python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataset

how would I  to merge data into python?

I need to merge data based on the date column, where the dates were the same, where I would have as input:

```
83423;01/06/2006;0000; ;30.5;  ;22.7;53.75;

83423;01/06/2006;1200;0;    ;16;    ;     ;
```

and the exit:

```
83423;01/06/2006;1200;0;30.5;16;22.7;53.75
```

How to merge?

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to SO. Unfortunately this isn't a discussion forum, tutorial or code writing service. Please take the time to read [ask] and the other links on that page.  You should spend some time working your way through [the Tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html), practicing the examples. It will give you an introduction to the tools Python has to offer and you may even start to get ideas for solving your problem. [Why “Can someone help me?” is not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to understand your question, as far as I can do now...

```
df = pandas.read_csv('your file name',sep=';', header=None)
df = df.groupby([1]).mean().reset_index()
```

then pick the column you need.

Comment: I have this entry:
83423; 06/01/2006; 0000; ; 30.5; ; 22.7; 53.75;

83423; 06/01/2006; 1200; 0; ; 16; ; ;

you see, the date is the same on line 1 and 2.
And there is a lack of data on line 2, which can be completed with line 1.
Where it is with NaN must be filled with the value that is in line 1 or line 2, where the "sum" of the two lines, forms a single.
The loopholes that are with NaN can be completed with the data that are in the other line.
Understood?

Comment: oh, sounds df = df.groupby([1]).mean().reset_index() will trickly fit your requirement.